# adding local printer via creating standard TCP/IP port vs adding network printer

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-printer, tcpip

My question is that what is the difference between adding local printer by creating standard TCP/IP port wizard and adding network printer wizard under device and printers in control panel?

It is very confusing for me to understand when and under what scenarios I would need to use local printer using standard TCP/IP port wizard and when and under what scenarios I would need to use adding network printer wizard method?

Answer (score 1):

Using the **Network Printer** option gives you more choices for how to connect to the printer.  Aside from the auto-search feature, you also have the ability to find the printer by share name or in the directory.

If you use the **Local Printer** option, on the other hand, you're limited to finding the printer by either host name or IP address.

Otherwise, the two methods are similar.